# How can write the string in the cursor's position?

Tags: vimscript-python

I write the function in my `.vimrc` which can convert string into its uppercase.

```
function! Cap(string)
python3 << EOF
s = vim.eval("a:string")
print(s.upper())
EOF
endfunction
```

Now i edit a file in vim,the cursor is at the beginning of the second line.

[image: the cursor's positioin]

I type `:call Cap("second line")`, `SECOND LINE` can show at the bottom, I want to write it at the second line when to type `:call Cap("second line")`:

[image: the result]

How to add some lines in function `Cap(string)` to achieve the target?

Comment: also note that `gU` is the upper-case operator, and `gUU` works on the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
function! Cap(string)
python3 << EOF
s = vim.eval("a:string")
s = s.upper()
# nb = int(vim.eval("line('.')"))
nb = vim.current.window.cursor[0]
vim.current.buffer.append(s, nb - 1)
EOF
endfunction
```

If you want to insert the string at cursor position you can do:

```
function! Cap(string)
python3 << EOF
s = vim.eval("a:string")
s = s.upper()
line_nb, col_nb = vim.current.window.cursor
line = vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1]
vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1] = line[:col_nb] + s + line[col_nb:]
EOF
endfunction
```

Comment: If the cursor located at the first line 20th column ,how can get the cursor's position with python code and add string at the position then?

Comment: ncol = vim.current.window.cursor[1]

Comment: `vim.current.buffer.append(s, nb - 1,ncol)` can't work.